# using regular expression that not include string '05613'. have NAW_05613_11_PL04_02 in table. need condition rows which have 05613 not be displayed

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to fetch data from database using regular expression which should not include string '05613'. 
I have values like NAW_05613_11_PL04_02 in my table. I want to give condition that all rows which have 05613 in it should not be displayed.

I have tried using `REGEXP_LIKE(d.variable_value_string, '^N(*)[^{05613}](*)')`

```
SELECT * from tablename where  REGEXP_LIKE(columnname, '^N(*)[^{05613}](*)')
```

Expected result should be- row with value having 05613 should not be retrieved.

Comment: `not like '%05613%'` should be enough I think... Is that what you wanna ask ?

Answer (score 3):

A simple `LIKE` could be enough:

```
... columnName not like '%05613%'
```

For example:

```
SQL> with test(c) as (
  2    select '05613XX' from dual union all
  3    select 'XX05613' from dual union all
  4    select 'X05613X' from dual union all
  5    select 'XXX' from dual
  6  )
  7  select *
  8  from test
  9  where c not like '%05613%';

C
-------
XXX

SQL>
```

If you need, for some reason, `regexp_like`, this is a way:

```
SQL> with test(c) as (
  2    select '05613XX' from dual union all
  3    select 'XX05613' from dual union all
  4    select 'XX05613' from dual union all
  5    select 'X05613X' from dual union all
  6    select 'XXX' from dual
  7  )
  8  select *
  9  from test
 10  where not regexp_like(c, '05613');

C
-------
XXX
```

Comment: I need to fetch it using regexp_like function only as it is being used in a package to capture other scenarios. So need help using this only..

Comment: The reason is not that clear to me; however, I just edited to show how regexp_like could do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your assignment and usage of `regexp_like` is mandated then use following `regexp_like`:

```
SELECT * from tablename D
where Not REGEXP_LIKE(d.variable_value_string, '05613')
```

Cheers!!

Comment: You can use `NOT` before `regexp_like`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi, I have only one function in the package which is using where regexp_like ..I cannot create not regexp_like too

Comment: create? what? This is just a usage of `NOT` against `regexp_like` to negate the result.

Comment: ya but we cannot add this in our code. This package is being called from front end. And there is not change in front end which will state it is not like some regular expression. So I need something which i can give in the query i mentioned only.